# How can you obtain an AST for Microsoft C++ (MSVC)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to be able to query what dependencies there are for C++ functions and variables in my source code. You could do that with Clang on the Linux side, but for Windows(.NET, etc) I can't seem to find a way to get access to the AST.

**Background**:
Say I fixed a part of my code. I'm trying to find a tool to easily identify all the areas in my source code affected by this fix.  For example, if I changed Foo(), I'll check all areas that Foo() is used and all functions that Foo() calls, gather them, and print them out in a list. Preferably, it will also be able to gather multiple levels of dependencies. If it were to be represented visually, it'll look something like [Sourcetrail](https://www.sourcetrail.com/). Unfortunately, I want to be able to do this programmatically instead of via a UI, so that link isn't what I'm looking for. I looked at [DMS Search Engine](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine/index.html?Home=CppTools) but I can't seem to make its trial version to download. So I was wondering if I can just do it myself. But I can't seem to figure out how Sourcetrail, for example, was able to get the AST from a Visual Studio C++ project.

Comment: Clang works on Windows just fine. Note this kind of question ("help me find a tool") is off topic here.

Comment: Clang works on Windows. And I've heard MSVC devs say that the compiler doesn't actually build an AST at all (but that they were working on it). I don't know what the status is with VS 2017 in this regard, but I can imagine VS 2013 or earlier simply not having one at all.

Comment: @n.m. Again, this question isn't asking to find a tool. See the "So I was wondering if I can just do it myself" in the question.

Comment: @hvd There is also the "I'm trying to find a tool to easily identify all the areas in my source code affected by this fix.".

Comment: @Ron As the first part of the background, leading up to the "do it myself".

Comment: @Angew If MSVC doesn't build an AST, then how can some of the C++ dependency-checking tools work for Visual Studio projects that does not use clang?

Comment: @marumaru They can build one themselves, I imagine.

Comment: I'm not a Windows developer, but as far as I know, can't you only use Clang for Windows if you had coded to compile with Clang? If you have a pre-existing Visual C++ project with .NET, could you still use clang?

Comment: @marumaru It's not 100% compatible, but I do know that Clang implements several extensions specifically for MSVC compatibility (behind the flag `-fms-extensions`, possibly enabled by default). If all non-standard extensions you're using are also implemented by Clang, then you can definitely use it.

Comment: Clang attempts to be compatible with MSVC, which is I guess as good as you can get. Come to think about it, MSVC is not always compatible with itself ( a different version of).

Comment: `clang-cl` uses MSVC (cl) style flags. No need to change the build files a lot.

Comment: MSVC++ today uses ASTs, they had to rewrite the front-end to become fully C++11 compatible.  But no, it has no option to expose them.  A tool like Sourcetrail does what it does by re-implementing a complete C++ parser.  They probably did not write one themselves, writing C++ a parser is *hard*, lots of companies use the front-end from EDG.  A company that gained fame and fortune by being the only one that ever wrote a parser that completely implemented C++03.  Microsoft uses them too for the IntelliSense parser.

Comment: Is it really that hard that I can't find any open source Visual C++ parser?

Comment: @marumaru What is so special about *Visual* C++ (and what exactly do you mean by that anyway) that you insist on parsing *that*?

Comment: Regarding not having an AST: see this [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Q-A-Panel) from July 2013 at 13:10 and again at 22:53. So I assume VS 2013 doesn't have one. Later versions might; I have no data there, but I'd trust @HansPassant.

Comment: There's no such thing as "open source Visual C++ parser". Visual C++ is not a language, so there's no parser *for* "Visual C++ language" (as there's no such language). C++ is a language, there are many parsers *for* C++. Visual C++ is a C++ implementation that contains a parser, but it's not open source, so you cannot have an open source parser that is a part of Visual C++.